# Which is better to use when creating derived object from base object: copy constructor or assignment operator?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
        Base () {cout << "\nBase Default Ctor";}
        Base (const Base& aObj) {cout << "\nCopy Ctor";}
        Base& operator=(const Base& aObj) {cout << "\nBase assignment operator";}
        ~Base() {cout << "\nBase Destructor";}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived () {cout << "\nDerived Default Ctor";}
        Derived (const Derived& aObj) {cout << "\nDerived Copy Ctor";}
        Derived (const Base& aObj) {cout << "\nDerived Copy Ctor using Base Object";}
        Derived& operator=(const Derived& aObj) {cout << "\nDerived Assignment operator";}

        Derived& operator=(const Base& aObj) {cout << "\nDerived Assignment operator using Base Object";}
        ~Derived () {cout << "\nDerived Destructor";}

};

int main ()
{
    Base bObj, bObj1;
    Derived dObj, dObj2;
    Derived dObj1 = bObj;
    dObj2 = bObj1;
    return 0;
}
```

Here I used two techniques to create derived object from base object.

1. Copy constructor: `Derived dObj1 = bObj;`
2. Assignment operator: first derived object is created with default constructor then base object is assigned to derived.

Which approach is better and why?

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question unless you've defined some semantics for the `Base` and `Derived` classes. You need to tell us what you're *actually* trying to do.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think here slicing is not come in picture. I am assigning base object to derived one. Slicing comes when derived object assign to base

Comment: Does it make any difference for your example? I dont think so. You have to come up with a better example, you are not assigning or copying anything here

Comment: @Spartacus you are correct, I misread the question.

Comment: Note that your example uses the "copy" constructor implicitly to convert `pObj1` to `Derived` before using `Derived& Derived::operator=(const Derived&)`. You may have meant to define a  `Derived& Derived::operator=(const Base&)`. I quote "copy" because it is not really a copy constructor, it merely looks like one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I updated the code. But question remain same. which is better to use

Comment: Sometimes you need assignment, sometimes you need copying. Neither is inherently *better* than the other - they serve different purposes - and both can usually be implemented equally efficiently.